# Межсерверная блокировка

Tags: java, ipc

В текущем проекте потребовалось реализовать блокировки между потенциально разнесенными инстансами. В данный момент выбрана связка Redis + Redisson, но она еле-еле взлетела (при большом количестве локов ожидаемо просела производительность + терялись локи, в результате самый напряженный участок удалось перенести на реализацию с Set, и только после этого все стало более-менее вменяемо, плюс данная реализация не подразумевает масштабирования Redis). Существуют ли альтернативные надежные реализации?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна реализация распределенной блокировки, если я правильно понимаю. Тогда смотрите на что-то из следующего: Apache Zookeeper, Netflix Eureka, Aapche Ignite, Hazelcast.

Если вы уже используете РСУБД, то можно использовать локи на транзакциях. Но это чревато падением производительности самой СУБД при большом количестве таких блокировок.

Comment: Да, предыдущая реализация была на СУБД, но то ли я провалил экзамен на дебила, то ли гибернейт не справился, но в самом простом тесте на оббивание сервиса запросами удалось выхватить две одинаковых сущности, несмотря на то, что исключения по поводу оптимистичного лока действительно появлялись, ловились и обрабатывались, как должны. Конкретно этот сервис не предполагается совсем бронебойным, там вряд ли когда-либо за сотню rps на кластер перевалит.